Is there transformed unit circles that represent transformed trigonometric functions?
I was doing some questions where we find general solutions for transformed trigonometric functions and I became deeply focused on the transformed general equation for such transformed functions. This is a result of the unit circle itself being transformed right? My question is is there even a concept such as a transformed unit circle? If so, what is it called? I am asking because I cannot find the concept when I searched it up.

By “transformed trigonometric functions” do you mean things like $\sin(x)+2$, $\cos(x-\frac{\pi}{2})$, etc?

Yes that was what I meant.

Let's take the function $f(x)=\tan(x)+2$. We know that $f\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\div\frac{1}{\sqrt2})+2=\boxed{3}$. However, this is not the same as taking $\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ of a unit circle translated $2$ units up, because then $\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+2)\div\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\approx\boxed{3.83}$, which is not equal to $3$. It seems like the transformed unit circle would only work for $y=\sin(x)+c$ and $y=\cos(x)+c$: the former works because it is of the form $\frac{\text{side length}}{\text{hypotenuse}}$ where the hypotenuse is $1$, which means there is no difference between $\frac{\text{side length}}{\text{hypotenuse}}+c$ (the normal function) and $\frac{\text{side length}+c}{\text{hypotenuse}}$ (the translated unit circle). The latter works because vertical translations of the unit circle have no effect on the horizontal coordinate used to calculate $\cos(x)$, which implies that $\sec(x)+c$ also works.
